# Trouble with language localization in Android. Application doesn't load necessary resourses from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, string, localization

I have an application which can be localized to many languages. But I have one big trouble. I have default file values/strings.xml where I store string in English by default and I have folder values-uk/strings.xml (for Ukrainian localization). I am saving the selected localization in SharedPreferences. The trouble is when the application starts without any selected language preference (but the system language of device is Ukrainian, I checked) my app must load Ukrainian strings from values-uk/strings.xml, but it loads English values from values/strings.xml. Can anyone explain me why this happens and how can I solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: show some code how you load language ??

Comment: Hm, but according to android documentation if application has folder with name values-XX that matches with device system device language then it loads all strings from that folder, not from default folder.

Comment: Soryy, but /res/values-uk-UA gives me invalid directory name error((

Answer (score 9):

Also always check your `build.gradle (app)` android/defaultConfig, if there set `resConfigs("en", "de", "ru"...)`. If yes only listed resources will leave in the project.

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day. I forget about this line in my build.gradle

Comment: At-last figure out why my translations isn't working just because i have write this line in my gradle (resConfigs :"en").

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Then I followed many tutorials. and finally I have used localization in my android application for all Indian Language. Have look at my code snippet:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        //SharedPreferences.Editor edit=getSharedPreferences("pref",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_assamese:
                setLocale("as");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_bihari:
                setLocale("bh");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_english:
                setLocale("en");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_gujarati:
                setLocale("gu");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_hindi:
                setLocale("hi");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_kannada:
                setLocale("kn");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_kashmiri:
                setLocale("ks");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_malayalam:
                setLocale("ml");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_marathi:
                setLocale("mr");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_oriya:
                setLocale("or");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_sanskrit:
                setLocale("sa");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_tamil:
                setLocale("ta");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_telgu:
                setLocale("te");
                return true;
            case R.id.action_urdu:
                setLocale("ur");
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
```

For more details you can follow [this](http://akhilgite.blogspot.in/2015/07/localization-in-android-app-supporting.html) tutorial.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok I will update it but This link provides complete tutorial. So I can add certain part. Either I have to copy all the text from that tutorial or I have to share the tutorial.